# Why join on subquery is so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider following query:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ...
LEFT JOIN table3 ...
LEFT JOIN table4 ...
LEFT JOIN table5 ...
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as qty FROM other WHERE ... GROUP BY id
) temp ON temp.id = table1.id
WHERE temp.qty = 123
GROUP BY table1.id
```

This query is very slow, however when I execute

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as qty FROM other WHERE ... GROUP BY id
```

alone, it's blazing fast, it returns only few (20-30) rows...

My current solution is a temporary table with index, I fill it with data, then I use join:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_counts;
CREATE TABLE tmp_counts id INT(11), qty INT(11) ...
INSERT INTO tmp_counts (id,qty) (SELECT id, COUNT(*) as qty FROM other WHERE ... GROUP BY id);
SELECT
  ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ...
LEFT JOIN table3 ...
LEFT JOIN table4 ...
LEFT JOIN table5 ...
LEFT JOIN tmp_counts ON tmp_counts.id = table1.id
WHERE tmp_counts.qty = 123
GROUP BY table1.id
```

It works very fast, but I feel like it's an ugly solution.

Is MySQL really that stupid I need to do mysql job manually by myself?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: @Brandon it uses indexes properly, subquery is marked as derived, temp table using where

Answer (score 3):

MySQL isn't *that* stupid.  Optimizing databases is complicated.  In fact, when you think about it, there is very little software that does such optimizations across such a large variety of different situations.  Procedural and object oriented languages -- they are told what to do.  In SQL, we say what we want and let the optimizer figure out the best.  What is best, in turn, can depend heavily on the underlying data.

Sometimes the optimizer is wrong.  Sometimes we can convince it otherwise.  The problem here is quite possibly the choice of join order or join algorithms.  One method to get around a problem like this is to replace the subquery with a correlated subquery in the `select`:

select

```
SELECT . . .,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM other
        WHERE . . . AND
              other.id = table1.id
       ) as qty
  ...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ...
LEFT JOIN table3 ...
LEFT JOIN table4 ...
LEFT JOIN table5 ...
GROUP BY table1.id;
```

This, in turn, can be further optimized by creating an index on `other`.  At the very least, this would be `other.id`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, probably you are right, I want too much from optimizer, I will stick with current solution, it's not that bad after all... And my real query is more complicated, I can't use query from your answer because it will be even slower

Comment: @Peter . . . How do you know it will be even slower without trying it?

Comment: I just tried it, I must admit it's  faster than my original query, but still slower than temporary table. (maybe because my subquery produces few rows?). Now I need to consider what to choose, because maybe in future my subquery may produce more rows...

Comment: @Peter . . . The table with the index will probably continue to perform best as the number of rows increases.  Having a real table gives the optimizer more information to work with, and the additional index is a big help.

Comment: Can you put it in a `having` clause, where such filtering normally belongs?